# Ignore special chars from string begins with @

Tags: php

A forum has the possibilty to mark members in the posts with @member. When a member has found with a @ in front, the @member word becomes a link and the @member gets notified. To check each word in a post, I use this pattern:

```
function display(&$text)
  {

    $pattern = '#<!\-\-([0-9]+):(@[^<>\s]+)\-\->#i';
    $text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    return get_followname_string('full', $matches['2'], $matches['1']);
    }, $text);

  }


function get_followname_string($mode, $follow_name, $user_id = 0)
{

   if(is_array($follow_name))
   {
    $user_id        = $follow_name['user_id'];
    $follow_name    = $follow_name['user_follow_name'];
   }

   if(strpos($follow_name, '@') !== 0)
   {
    $follow_name = '@' . $follow_name;
   }

return '<a class="mention" href="' . $profile_url . '">' . $follow_name . '</a>';
}
```

**Problem:**

When the @word has a dot, a comma, a questionmark or anything else at the end, this pattern does not match the member.

Example:  @member. (does not work)

What is the best way to archive this? I see two possiblities.

1, Add a space between the @word and the .,?!.
2, Dont take care (ignore) of special chars like .,?! at the end and the @mark will work nevertheless.

Comment: Where are you calling display exactly? What kind of relationship there is between display function and get_followname_string?

Comment: Hello, the get_followname_string comes after the pattern. I think it should be possible with the pattern alone?